# How to make niceditor readonly?

Tags: nicedit

I have some textareas in my page. I converted all into niceeditor with the option provided. I will save the content of the niceditor into my database. While i am retrieving, i will get the html tagged data. I am showing the text in my page.

So to show the rich text of what i enter. I should make niceditor. So that i could show the rich text. And also it should be readonly.

Please guide me to make niceditor readonly or guide me to show the rich text without editing option through some way.

my textarea name is 'area3'.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `div` instead of `textarea`? Nicedit supports convert `div`s too , You can toggle nicedit on or off.